# Group by month, week using date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
user,dates,quantity,location
```

and I am thinking of useful group by procedures to make.

```
 pd.to_numeric(x['quantity'], errors='coerce').groupby(x['user']).sum().reset_index()
```

gives this:

```
    user      quanity
0   user_01    8900.0
1   user_02       0.0
2   user_03       0.0
3   user_04     232.0
4   user_05      21.0
5   user_06     110.0
6   user_07     240.0
7   user_08   20500.0
```

How can I do this including `location` and `dates`?

Example: to be able to easily change between weekly checks or by month?

Note: the dates column is of object type

sample data

```
     dates      user   quantity  location
0   2018-09-03  user_01 23          GR
1   2018-09-03  user_01 -           GR
2   2018-09-03  user_02 3           SW
3   2018-09-03  user_03 -           POR
4   2018-09-03  user_04 222         PAN
5   2018-09-03  user_04 -           PAN
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input data with expected output?

Comment: ok   just wait a moment         .

Comment: is it sufficient if I copy them in the question or you want a file?

Comment: Better is add sample data to question. e.g. 5 rows.

Comment: See update in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby by multiply columns and aggregate `sum`:

```
x['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(x['quantity'], errors='coerce')
df = x.groupby(['dates','user','location'], as_index=False)['quantity'].sum()
print (df)
        dates     user location  quantity
0  2018-09-03  user_01       GR      23.0
1  2018-09-03  user_02       SW       3.0
2  2018-09-03  user_03      POR       0.0
3  2018-09-03  user_04      PAN     222.0
```

EDIT: You can use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) by `MS` start of months - check [offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
x['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(x['dates'])

x['quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(x['quantity'], errors='coerce')
df = (x.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dates', freq='MS'),'user','location'])['quantity']
       .sum()
       .reset_index())

print (df)
       dates     user location  quantity
0 2018-09-01  user_01       GR      23.0
1 2018-09-01  user_02       SW       3.0
2 2018-09-01  user_03      POR       0.0
3 2018-09-01  user_04      PAN     222.0
```

Or use [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) or
[`day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) or 
[`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df = x.groupby([x['dates'].dt.month,'user','location'])['quantity'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   dates     user location  quantity
0      9  user_01       GR      23.0
1      9  user_02       SW       3.0
2      9  user_03      POR       0.0
3      9  user_04      PAN     222.0
```

Comment: i need to do checks by week, month, things like that. Ex. If needed group by month to group by the second part of the date (09). Is it clear?How can I do this for week ,month etc?

Comment: This checks by month and here is Sep?Is it possible to turn 09 to Sep?

Comment: Sure, change `x['dates'].dt.month` to `x['dates'].dt.strftime('%b')`, check [http://strftime.org/](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: daymm.This is amazing.